# react-admin graphql data provider: how to implement GET_MANY if GraphQL API only supports GET_ONE?

Tags: graphql, react-admin

How to implement a `GET_MANY` data provider function in react-admin's `ra-data-graphql` package if the GraphQL API only supports the equivalent `GET_ONE`?

I understand how it can be done with REST by waiting on resolving all promises of the API call, but here the return from `buildQuery` is supposed to be an object with a key for the GraphQL query, and a key for a function parsing the response.

So how can this support multiple GraphQL queries, one for each ID we want to fetch, before we return the result from the data provider for `GET_MANY`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

@kurtko sorry for late reply. Just checking this now. Found a workaround that does not require changes to GQL schema (since that is an external API I cannot change).
You need to make changes to `ra-data-graphql`. Basically you need to allow for multiple GQL queries and then await until all promises resolve and return a combined result. By using either `query` or `queries` you can instruct ra-data-graphql to either run a single or multiple GQL queries. I modified index.js as follows:

```
// GRAPHQL QUERY
    if (operation === 'query') {
      if (!query.queries) {
        // single GraphQL query
        const apolloQuery = {
          ...query,
          fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
          ...getOptions(otherOptions.query, aorFetchType, resource),
        };

        return client
          .query(apolloQuery)
          .then((response) => parseResponse(response))
          .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error.message));
      } else {
        // multiple GraphQL queries
        const prs = query.variables.map((variables) => {
          const { queries, ...rest } = query;
          const apolloQuery = {
            ...rest,
            query: queries,
            variables,
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
            ...getOptions(otherOptions.query, aorFetchType, resource),
          };
          return client.query(apolloQuery);
        });
        return Promise.all(prs)
          .then((responses) => parseResponse(responses))
          .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error.message));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved with schema like this: (look `{ids: [ID]}` in `UserFilter` it's the important thing)

```
type Query {        
      Post(id: ID!): Post  
      allPosts(page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: PostFilter): [Post]
      _allPostsMeta(page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: PostFilter): ListMetadata
      User(id: ID!): User 
      allUsers(page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: UserFilter): [User]
      _allUsersMeta(page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: UserFilter): ListMetadata
}    

type User {
     id: ID!
     name: String!
     views: Int!
}

type Post {
     id: ID!
     title: String!
     views: Int!
     body: String
     user_id: ID!  
     User: User   
}        

input PostFilter {
      q: String
      id: ID
      title: String
      views: Int
      views_lt: Int
      views_lte: Int
      views_gt: Int
      views_gte: Int
      user_id: ID
}

input UserFilter {
    q: String
    ids: [ID]
    title: String
    views: Int
    views_lt: Int
    views_lte: Int
    views_gt: Int
    views_gte: Int
    user_id: ID
}

type ListMetadata {
    count: Int!
}
```